# Page break in html doesn't work as expected when I print the html with Print API in Expo (iOS)

Tags: html, ios, react-native, expo

I tried to add page break to an html and print the html using [Expo Print API](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/print/) in my Expo app.

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
<h1>Page 3</h1>
<div class="pagebreak"></div>
</body>
<style>
@page print {
    .pagebreak { break-before: page; }
}
@media print {
    .pagebreak { break-before: page; }
}
@page print {
    .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; }
}
@media print {
    .pagebreak { break-before: always; }
}
</style>
</html>
```

However in iOS, none of these styles work.

[image]

But one of them work in android. Keep below style only,

```html
@media print {
    .pagebreak { break-before: page; }
}
```

then pick android mode in expo snack, then we find the expected page break.

[image]

The reproducible example: [Expo snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@evanchan/expo-print-page-break). I care about iOS mode only, so no need to worry about android or web.

Note: the question is similar to [How to avoid page breaks inside content sections in output PDF generated from HTML using Expo.printToFileAsync on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367385/how-to-avoid-page-breaks-inside-content-sections-in-output-pdf-generated-from-ht) but that question does not provide a reproducible example and its description contains some redundant information. That's why I create a new question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue looks to be an issue with iOS Safari support for `@print` and `page-break-before` and/or `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` (https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-print/ios/EXPrint/EXPrint.m#L78).

Here's a workaround with CSS you can use instead of page breaks that achieves the same effect: wrap each page in a `wrapper` CSS class and make it take the height of a full page.

**CSS**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 32px); 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

More info in Expo issues: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6680#issuecomment-578353288. Will edit this answer if a better solution is added.